# Central Limit Theorem help needed

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Good evening. I have tried to solve this problem with many approaches but I have not succeeded yet.

A man wants to estimate the mean number of water in meters cubed in a village. Sample used is $45$ tanks and std deviation is $2$. I have to use central limit theorem to find the probability that the error will be less than 1m cubed and less than $0.5$ m cubed.

I started out by solving to find the mean by saying standard deviation/sq root of $n = \frac{2}{6.71} = 0.298$.

I am kind of stuck as to what to do next do I have to find the $z$ value and if so what would be the values needed? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are assuming that the amount of water in a tank is normally distributed with unknown mean $\mu$ and unknown standard deviation $\sigma$, is that right?  I don't think that that follows directly from the central limit theorem without some additional assumptions, but it is the usual form for this sort of homework problem.  If I am wrong about that, please disregard the remainder of this answer.

---

The man is going to estimate $\mu$ by taking the sample mean $\bar{x}$ of the $45$ values he has measured. We want to know that probability that the error $\vert \bar{x}-\mu\vert$ is less than $1$.

To do this, we have to consider the distribution of the statistic $\bar{x}$. As I think you know, $\bar{x}$ is distributed normally with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma/\sqrt{45}$.

If we knew $\sigma$, it would be easy from here, since the statistic $$Z=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{45}}$$ would have the standard normal deviation.

However, it's at this point that we run into a problem: we do not know $\sigma$!
What we do know is $s$, the *sample* standard deviation.  Fortunately for us, it is for precisely this situation that the $t$-distribution was invented.  So, instead of the $Z$ statistic above, we use the following $T$-statistic:
$$T=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{s/\sqrt{45}}.$$
This statistic follows the $t$-distribution with 44 degrees of freedom.

(The statistic $s$ is an estimator for the parameter $\sigma$, but like any estimator, it is imperfect.  This imperfection is a source of noise.  If we were to pretend that $s=\sigma$, then we would underestimate the variability in our distribution for $\bar{x}$, 
and thus underestimate the probability that $\vert \bar{x}-\mu\vert > 1$.)

Since we want to know the probability that $\vert \bar{x}-\mu\vert<1$ we want the  probabilities of the events that $\frac{-1}{s/\sqrt{45}}<T<\frac{1}{s/\sqrt{45}}$.  Since $s=2$, and applying the fact that a $t$ distribution is symmetric about $0$, this becomes:
$$1-2\cdot P\left[ T<\frac{-1}{0.298}\right].$$

Going to the first $t$-distribution calculator I found on Google (http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/t-distribution.aspx), I found that this probability is $1-2\times 0.0008=0.9984$.

I'll leave you to work out for yourself the probability that the error is less than $0.5$.

---

Since you mention "finding the $z$-value", I guess that there is a chance that your class expects you to use the $Z$ statistic rather than the $T$-statistic, by assuming that $\sigma=2$.

In this case, we know that $\bar{x}$ is distributed normally with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $2/\sqrt{45}=0.298$ and the error term $\bar{x}-\mu$ is distributed normally with mean $0$ and standard deviation $0.298$.  You want to find the probability that the absolute value of the error term is less than $1$.  This is the same as the probability that $$\vert Z\vert<\frac{1}{2/\sqrt{45}}=3.354 $$ where $Z$ has the standard normal distribution.  Using a $z$-caluclator, or tables, we see that $P[Z<-3.354]=0.0004$, and so the probability that $\vert Z\vert < 3.354$ is $0.9992$.

Note that this is higher than the probability calculated using the $t$-distribution, since by assuming that $\sigma=2$,  we are making stronger assumptions about the tightness of the distribution of the estimate $\bar{x}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help Things are much clearer, As far as I understood the standard deviation is not given it just says that the man knows from experience that the standard deviation is 2 for such data, so im guessing thats not the required standard deviation?

Comment: "The man knows from experience that the standard deviation is $2$ for such data."  That is exactly the terminology that textbooks tend to use when they want you to use the $Z$ test rather than the $T$ test.  It isn't terribly convincing, but it serves a pedagogical purpose: in practice it is hardly every appropriate to use the $Z$ test rather then the $T$ test (unless the sample size is in excess of 100 or so), but the $Z$ test is a simpler test to use, and so is often taught to students before the $T$ test.  So, in short, you should use what I wrote in the bit below the horizontal rule.

Comment: okay I understand thank you